# how to request for refunds in paypal using paypal-recurring gem in (ruby on rails) application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, payment, paypal-sandbox

Using paypal-recurring gem, how can we ask for full refunds for a recurring profile? I'm using Ruby on Rails for developing my application. I tried searching for it, but didn't found appropriate answer to my problem.

I've found this link:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/refundtransaction-api-operation-soap

But I don't understand how to integrate it with my app.

I'm using this gem,

https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring

And my code is as follows:

```
def refund_full_paypal_transaction     

  PayPal::Recurring.new({
    :profile_id     => "customers profile id",
    :transaction_id => "to_be_refunded transaction_id",
    :reference      => "12345",
    :refund_type    => :full,
    :amount         => "whatever amount",
    :currency       => "USD"
    })

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the gem already provides RefundTransaction for you.  I'm not a Ruby developer, but if you look at /lib/paypal/recurring/request.rb you'll see it's a simple class that builds your API requests for you.

The METHODS array at the top specifies the different requests that it seems to support, and RefundTransaction is one of them.

So again, I can't give too detailed an answer without knowing Ruby better, but from what I see you can simply pass in the refund attribute there along with the original transaction ID to be refunded and it'll handle the rest for you.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

# Request a refund.

```
    ppr = PayPal::Recurring.new({
        :profile_id => "I-VCEL6TRG35CU",
       :transaction_id => "ABCEDFGH",
       :reference      => "1234",
       :refund_type    => :partial,
       :amount         => "9.00",
       :currency       => "USD"
     })
     response = ppr.refund
```

worked !!! found in https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring/blob/master/lib/paypal/recurring/base.rb

Thanks !!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help.  Ruby does look pretty interesting.  I may have to start playing with it.  :)